# Stick-To-Edge animation after dragging

Tags: android, animation

I want to make a chathead like one of facebook. As you can see, when you drag the chat head, it moves around following your finger (<- Okay I can handle it). After you release your finger, the chat head will move/stick to the left/right edge of the screen. You can check this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECLkrDfDAG4)

EDIT:

Following some instruction of Junior Buckeridge, this effect is done! But it doesn't look smooth although I vary the params :(. Check the [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_y0PjeXlNo&feature=youtu.be)

Here is my code:

```
        iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = params.x;
                initialY = params.y;
                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                while (params.x > 0
                        && params.x < outMetrics.widthPixels - 3)
                    if (params.x <= outMetrics.widthPixels / 2) {
                        TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
                                params.x, params.x - 3,
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF);
                        params.x -= 3;
                        animate.setDuration(100);
                        animate.setFillAfter(true);
                        iv.setAnimation(animate);
                        manager.updateViewLayout(iv, params);
                    } else {
                        TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
                                params.x, params.x + 3,
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF);
                        params.x += 3;
                        animate.setDuration(100);
                        animate.setFillAfter(true);
                        iv.setAnimation(animate);
                        manager.updateViewLayout(iv, params);
                    }
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                params.x = initialX
                        + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                params.y = initialY
                        + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                manager.updateViewLayout(iv, params);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please share some samples I'm stuck in such kind of animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must handle the (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP | MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) events to determine the current position of the event. Then calculate the device width and proceed according to the overlay position.
You can get the device width using

```
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int w = dm.widthPixels;
boolean goLeft = (event.getRawX() > width/2 - view.getWidth()/2) ? false : true;
```

Edit:
If you want to set an animation, and you're outside an activity context (something that I assume 'cause otherwise using a TranslateAnimation would be straightforward), you must create a basic animation that updates layout params in time. Something like:

```
while(true){
        if(goLeft){
            if(view.getLeft()/2>0){
                left -= LEFT_STEP;
            }else{
                left = 0;
                break;
            }

        }else{
            if(view.getRight()<w){
                left += LEFT_STEP;
            }else{
                left = w - view.getWidth();
                break;
            }

        }

        SystemClock.sleep(SLEEP_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
    }
```

Try varying the params to get a smooth animation.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I know that is the condition to decide if the chathead goes left or right. But I want the ANIMATION that make the chathead go smooth to the edge. I cant figure out.

Comment: Ok it's really late at night in my country now. I'll try your suggestion tomorrow and report soon:)

Comment: It doesn't look very smooth. I still accept your answer. But can you help me make it looks smoother? See my edit plz :)

Comment: Try using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html#TranslateAnimation(int, float, int, float, int, float, int, float)  or maybe just animating your view using a custom thread. The latter has work better for me when interacting directly with the window manager to display an overlay cause I can handle better garbage collection.